# Getting not InMemoryUploadedFile error while trying to upload image

Tags: python, django

I'm learning to upload image via form in django but getting error

TypeError at /panel/add-news/
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Not getting what i'm missing

forms.html

```
<form action="{%url 'add_news' %}" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input type="text" id="newstitle" name="newstitle" class="form-control" placeholder="News Title" >
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <select id="example-chosen" id="newscat" name="newscat" class="select-chosen" data-placeholder="Category..." style="width: 250px;">
                                                        <option></option><!-- Required for data-placeholder attribute to work with Chosen plugin -->
                                                        <option value="cat1">cat 1</option>
                                                        <option value="cat2">cat 2</option>
                                                        <option value="cat3">cat 3</option>
                                                    </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <textarea type="text" id="newstxtshort" name="newstxtshort" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Short text"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <textarea type="text" id="newstxt" name="newstxt" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Body text"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <input type="file" id="file" name="myfile" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Body text">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Submit</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </form>
```

path in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls in main/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # path(r"admin/", admin.site.urls),
    # path(r"", include('main.urls'))
    url(r"admin/", admin.site.urls),
    url(r"", include("main.urls")),
    url(r"", include("news.urls")),

    ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Models.py:

```
class News(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    headline = models.TextField()  # short_text in place of title in course
    body_text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    pic = models.TextField()
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    catname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="-")
    catid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    show = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my Views.py method that handles forms data:

```
def add_news(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newstitle = request.POST.get('newstitle')
        category = request.POST.get('newscat')
        shorttext = request.POST.get('newstxtshort')
        bodytxt = request.POST.get('newstxt')

        if newstitle == "" or shorttext == "" or bodytxt == "" or category == "":
            error = "All fields required"
            return render(request, 'back/error.html', {'error': error})

        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        filename = fs.save(myfile, myfile)
        media_url = fs.url(filename)
        b = News(name=newstitle, headline=shorttext, body_text=bodytxt, pic=media_url, writer='vineet', catname=category,
                 catid=0, show=0)
        b.save()
        return redirect('news_list')
    return render(request, 'back/news_add.html')
```

Though i can see in django error page it is able to find file that i want to upload:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKZU7.png)

Comment: Can you try this? b = News(name=newstitle, headline=shorttext, body_text=bodytxt, pic=media_url.file, writer='vineet', catname=category,
                 catid=0, show=0)

Comment: @LearningNoob tried, same error.